Fluent-Bit Structured Json Splitting
There is a log template that comes from our applications. I am trying to send logs to Elastic Search/Kibana with fluent-bit according to the fields here.but I can't parse the data in json. it all comes under a single tag (log).
Below I share the configuration files
custom_parsers.conf
[PARSER]

    Name         docker_new

    Format       json

    Time_Key     @timestamp

    Time_Format  %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z

    Time_Keep    On

    # Command      |  Decoder | Field | Optional Action

    # =============|==================|=================

    Decode_Field_As   escaped_utf8    log    do_next```


**fluent-bit.conf
[SERVICE] 
    Daemon Off 
    Flush 1
    Log_Level debug 
    Parsers_File /fluent-bit/etc/parsers.conf 
    Parsers_file /fluent-bit/etc/conf/custom_parsers.conf 
    HTTP_Server On 
    HTTP_Listen 0.0.0.0 
    HTTP_Port 2020 
    Health_Check On

[INPUT] 
    Name tail 
    Path /var/log/containers/* 
    Parser docker_new 
    Tag kube.* 
    Mem_Buf_Limit 5MB 
    Skip_Long_Lines On

[INPUT] 
    Name systemd 
    Tag host.* 
    Systemd_Filter _SYSTEMD_UNIT=kubelet.service 
    Read_From_Tail On

[FILTER] 
    Name kubernetes 
    Match kube.* 
    Merge_Log On 
    Keep_Log Off 
    K8S-Logging.Parser On 
    K8S-Logging.Exclude Off

[OUTPUT] 
    Name es 
    Match kube.* 
    Index fluent-bit 
    Type  _doc 
    Host elasticsearch-master Port 9200 
    HTTP_User elastic_user 
    HTTP_Passwd elastic_password 
    tls On 
    tls.verify Off 
    Logstash_Format On 
    Logstash_Prefix logstash 
    Retry_Limit False 
    Suppress_Type_Name On 
    Replace_Dots On 
    Trace_Error on

[OUTPUT] 
    Name es 
    Match host.* 
    Index fluent-bit 
    Type  _doc 
    Host elasticsearch-master 
    Port 9200 
    HTTP_User elastic_user 
    HTTP_Passwd elastic_password 
    tls On 
    tls.verify Off 
    Logstash_Format On 
    Logstash_Prefix node 
    Retry_Limit False 
    Suppress_Type_Name On 
    Replace_Dots On 
    Trace_Error on
**

**Our JSON Log Template;**


{
  "correlationId": "b84a74-12345-46d9-a78f-978ceefb5452",
  "agentName": "unknown",
  "severity": "Information",
  "app": null,
  "service": "Account.Infrastructure.Consumers.SettingsUpdateEventConsumer",
  "env": null,
  "host": "account",
  "message": "{\"DomainName\":\"website.com\",\"Key\":\"SiteSettings\",\"CorrelationId\":null,\"Id\":\"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000\",\"Timestamp\":0,\"Version\":0}",
  "stackTrace": null,
  "date": "2024-10-11T06:42:32.005Z", 
  "@timestamp": "2024-10-11T06:42:32.005Z"
}


All the data in this json is listed in the log field, I want to see them one by one in separate fields.
